# Fail to inject log4j using CDI - WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default

Tags: logging, jsf-2, cdi, managed-bean

I do have the same issue as explained here: [JBoss7.1.3: @EJB works while @Inject fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672051/jboss7-1-3-ejb-works-while-inject-fails)
Presumably that is even the same setup (Wildfly 8.0).

Despite having a Resource class with producer, I cannot inject a Logger instance. Neiter in the Controller, nor into the EJB. [Question 1] Correct me if I'm wrong, I should be able to inject them into @Model beans and into beans annotated with @Stateless (EJB), shouldn't I?

```
package com.doe.webapp.service.auxilliary.cdiproducer;

import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    @Dependent
    public class Resources {

        @Produces
        public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
            return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
        }

        @Produces
        @RequestScoped
        public FacesContext produceFacesContext() {
            return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        }
    }
```

Here is the start of my Controller:

```
package com.doe.webapp.controller.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;    
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;    
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import com.doe.webapp.model.usermgmt.User;
import com.doe.webapp.service.security.LoginService;

@Model
public class LoginController {

    private static final String ADMIN = "admin";

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private LoginService loginService;

   [...]
```

Here is the EJB, which is also Injected in the @Model annotated class. Likewise the Logger. While the former works, the injection of the Logger throws the previously explained error.

```
package com.doe.webapp.service.security;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.doe.webapp.data.UserRepository;
import com.doe.webapp.model.usermgmt.User;

@Stateless
public class LoginService {

    @Inject
    private transient Logger log;

    @Inject
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Inject
    private Event<User> userEvent;

    public User login(User user) {
        log.info("login " + user.getUsername());
        User rUser = repository.findByCredentials(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        return rUser;
    }
}
```

Now, I get an error for the LoginController.java Controller.

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.doe.webapp.controller.security.LoginController.log
  at com.doe.webapp.controller.security.LoginController.log(LoginController.java:0)
```

And another one for the LoginService.java Enterprise Bean.

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private transient com.doe.webapp.service.security.LoginService.log
  at com.doe.webapp.service.security.LoginService.log(LoginService.java:0)
```

[Question 2]: What am I not understanding that this injection fails with the WELD-001408 error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have a Wildfly/JBoss environment right now, but one possible mistake:

`LoginService` imports and wants to inject the following:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

...

@Inject
private transient Logger log;
```

`LoginController` tries to use SLF4J:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;

...

@Inject
private Logger log;
```

While the `Resources` class uses a third type of `Logger`:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the exception with the EJB (LoginService.java)! (If I could upvote, I would!). Now the ManagedBean (LoginController.java) is left with the exception as before:  `WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.doe.webapp.controller.security.LoginController.log
  at com.doe.webapp.controller.security.LoginController.log(LoginController.java:0)`

Comment: @feder: Are you sure that you changed the imports in all of the three places?

Comment: You are right. One pointed to `org.apache.log4j.Logger`, the other to `org.log4j.Logger`. Well guessed!

Comment: I was to hasty. The variable instance `log` always returns null when I want to print a log entry. Thus, it throws a Nullpointer exception, whenever I want to access the variables methods. Any clue why that is? this is the error message: http://pastebin.com/r8A6qK38

Comment: @feder: Injection happens after constructor calls, so you can't use injected field in the constructor. Try to use a `@PostConstruct` method which is run after injection.

Comment: @feder: If that's not the case ask a new question about that please, it would be easier to follow.